# Deleting localized languages from windows 8 app before publishing it

Tags: windows-8, publishing

When I upload my app package(.appxupload) in windows Dev Center- windows Store apps, I am asked to provide description for the app in English, Belarusian, and catalan. But I do not want my app to be published in any other language than English. How do i remove Belarusian and Catalan from the description? 
I tried making changes to Package.storeAssociation.xml file,by deleting all the languages other than English. But during the packaging of my project it resets back to the original settings. 
I have selected only India in markets that i want to sell.

It would be great if someone could help me out with this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you supply additional .resw files for languages besides English? If so you need to delete these .resw files from the project before building the App-Package.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set your languages in "Package.appxmanifest" file on Solution Explorer. And if you want to only publish your app in English set "Default Language" (Application Tab) setting to "en-US".